# Changes made to response object in IActionFilter are not applied

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, action-filter

I am changing some fields in response object in IActionFilter:

```
public async void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    ObjectResult actionResult = (ObjectResult)context.Result;
    IHavePrice havePrice = Cast<IHavePrice>(actionResult.Value);
    var items = await _priceSetter.GetPrices<IHavePrice>(username, new List<IHavePrice>() { havePrice });
    havePrice = items[0];    
}
```

The code works: I can see changes in context.Result.Value. But on frontend I receive old values in response object.

Comment: You are not setting the value back to the `actionResult`.

Comment: Even if `actionResult` was modified, `async void` is an equally serious bug. That syntax is *only* meant for event handlers. Such methods can't be awaited. This means that the caller never awaits for `GetPrices` to complete and the response object can easily be disposed by the time

Comment: Use `async Task` for methods that don't return anything, not `async void`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You were right! After I deleted await and async the changes were applied. But I want to keep using async here. Could you post answer with  AsyncActionFilter (it has only one method OnActionExecutionAsync, not clear how to use it)?